# Setting a Radio button from a text document using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

So you may remember me from last week (college student) i'm now trying to get my radio buttons to remember what was entered when the page is refreshed or navigated back to. So i'm using text documents to save the answers which works a dream with everything on my site so far, however i'm having an issue getting them to send the data back to the radio buttons. Anyone know how to do this?

```
<?php
    ob_clean();session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    //Send Data
    $tb1 = $_POST['radio1']."\r\n";
    $tb2 = $_POST['radio2']."\r\n";
    $tb3 = $_POST['rasio3']."\r\n";
    $tb4 = $_POST['radio4']."\r\n";
    $tb5 = $_POST['rasio5']."\r\n";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio1.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $tb1);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio2.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $tb2);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio3.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $tb3);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio4.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $tb4);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio5.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $tb5);
    fclose($myFile);    

    header( 'Location: http://www.murphy.sulmaxmarketing.com/GeneralImpressionPt2.php' ) ;
    }



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>General Impression Part 1</title>

        <link href="CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body link="black">
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

        <div id="borderDiv">
            <div id="navDiv">

                <div id="backNavDiv">   
                    <a href="FeedbackGivenReceived.php"><font color="#0099FF"><p align="left"><b>&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Feedback</b></p></font></a>
                </div>

                 <div id="logoutDiv">
                    <a href="index.php?logout"><font color="#0099FF"><p align="right"><b>Logout&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</b></p></font></a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="headerDiv">
                <p>General Impression Part 1</p>
            </div>

            <div id="subHeaderDiv">
                <p>CULTURE</p>
            </div>

            <form action="GeneralImpressionPt1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name"FileForm" id="FileForm">
            <label for="FormField"></label>
            <p>Is the CDP obvious - You Said / We Did Boards; Feedback Stations; Posters?</p>
                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1"> 1<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2"> 2<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="3"> 3<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="4"> 4<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="5"> 5<br>
                </div>

            <p>Are there any Speak Up Coaches on this site?</p>
                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="1"> 1<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2" > 2<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="3"> 3<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="4"> 4<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="5"> 5<br>
                </div>

            <p>Are Focus Leader meetings happening?</p>
                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="1"> 1<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="2"> 2<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="3"> 3<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="4"> 4<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="5"> 5<br>
                </div>  

            <p>Mention the Mental Tools – do people understand them?</p>
                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="1"> 1<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="2"> 2<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="3" > 3<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="4" > 4<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="5" > 5<br>
                </div>  

            <p>Ask what ‘Never Harm’ means to the teams.</p>
                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="1"> 1<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="2"> 2<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="3"> 3<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="4"> 4<br>
                </div>

                <div id="radioBtnDiv">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="5"> 5<br>
                </div>                  

            <div id="loginBtnDiv">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
            </div>

            </form>


      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not that this is the answer to your problem but in your `form`, the `name` attribute is missing the `=` sign

Comment: since your form is submitting to a different page (`GeneralImpressionPt1.php`), then you need to use SESSIONS. On the receiving page you set the sessions, then on your `form` you check if the sessions are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve the information on documents and then try to check each radio button if it corresponds to input checked. For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
  ...
}else{

   $filename = "DATA/GIP1_Radio1.txt";
   $handle1 = fopen($filename,"r") or exit("Can’t open file!");
   $radio1 = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
   fclose($handle);

//The same for all files...
}
```

And then, in the html part, check if the input is the same as the stored in file:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" <?php if($radio1 == 1){ echo "checked"; ?>>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2" <?php if($radio1 == 2){ echo "checked"; ?>>
...
```

Comment: On the `$handle1` is that different to `$handle` on the next two lines?

Comment: Also I'm getting a syntax error on the line `<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" <?php if($radio1 == 1){ echo "checked"; ?>>`

Comment: Found it you forgot to close of the if statement

Comment: Yes, sorry, I write it quick. It should be 'handle' without the 1, or make: handle1, handle2, handle3.. in all the occurrences